# What's generally considered as the best size for full screen background image?

Tags: html, css, background, background-image

On an average, what should be the size of the image for full-screen background?

I'm currently using a 1920x1080 pixels image, would that be ok or is it too small for desktop size screens?

Comment: try to use 1600x800 width images

Comment: totally depends on your users. If you have many users with (big) imacs a bigger resolution would be better.

Comment: @ram wouldn't the image look stretched on larger screens?

Comment: @cloned would 3000x3000 be ok?

Comment: If you want it to run perfectly, create multiple resolutions of the image and serve it as background depending on `@media min(or max)-width`.

Comment: You need to assume any large size of screen it's up to you but (" max-width ") is required for any image if you want that it will not stretched

Comment: @Sandy If a computer's resolution is 3000x3000, a 3000x3000 image would be perfect.  Otherwise no.

Comment: `<picture>` is the way.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the native resolution of your screen.
The image used should match the native resolution of your screen for the best result.

There is a couple of things you can do to adress this issue since people will be using different screen sizes.

1. Dynamicly generate your background; this limits you to the use of pure symetrical images
2. Upload multiple sizes of your background image, grab the screen resolution from the users user-agent and display the correct size image.

Comment: More on dynamic image sizes here: [MDN srcset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#attr-srcset)